# Argument of class is not iterable

Tags: python, class

So I'm trying to replicate the [Enigma Machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enigma_machine), and one of the things I'm trying to make is the `Plugboard`. So the class `PlugLead` is meant to establish a connection between two letters. `Plugboard` has two functions, add (which adds the connection between two letters to the Plugboard) and encode gets the linked letter.

```
class PlugLead:
  def __init__(self, mapping):
    self.mapping = mapping

  def __str__(self):
    return self.mapping

  def __repr__(self):
    return self.mapping

  def encode(self, character):
    leads = self.mapping

    if character not in leads:
      return character
    else:
      if character == leads[0]:
        return leads[1]
      else:
        return leads[0]
    return leads
```

```
class Plugboard:

  def __init__(self):
    self.arr = []

  def __str__(self):
    return (f'Mapping:{self.arr}')

  def __repr__(self):
    return (f'Mapping:{self.arr}')

  def add(self,connection):
    self.arr.append(connection)

  def encode(self,letter):
    for i in range(0,len(self.arr)-1):
      if letter in self.arr[i]:
        return self.arr[i].replace(letter, '')
    raise ValueError("Character can not be encoded")
```

```
plugboard = Plugboard()
plugboard.add(PlugLead("AR"))
plugboard.add(PlugLead("BT"))
assert(plugboard.encode("A") == "R")
```

I get the error:

```
TypeError: argument of type 'PlugLead' is not iterable
```

So I think I get that `PlugLead(string)` doesn't return a string, but I'm not sure how to get it to return a string so I can use it in other classes.

Comment: In your own words, when you write `if letter in self.arr[i]:`, what do you think that should mean? Where do you actually want to look for the `letter`?

Comment: The elements of `Plugboard.arr` are PlugLead objects.  If you want to read the strings from there, you'll need `self.arr[i].mapping`, or `str(self.arr[i])`, although that's a bit non-intuitive.

Comment: (Hint: in your own words, why does the `PlugLead` class also have an `encode` method? Do you suppose it might be helpful in solving the problem?)

Comment: On a more profound level, what is `PlugLead` really doing for you?  Why couldn't you just use the 2-character strings themselves?

Answer (score 1):

You can implement a `__contains__()` method in your class so that the `in` operator is implemented.

```
class PlugLead:
  def __init__(self, mapping):
    # Your code here
    self.mapping = mapping 

  def __str__(self):
    return self.mapping 

  def __repr__(self):
    return self.mapping

  def __contains__(self, item):
    return item in self.mapping

  def encode(self, character):
    leads = self.mapping
        
    if character not in leads:
      return character
    else:
      if character == leads[0]:
        return leads[1]
      else:
        return leads[0]
    return leads
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everyone for the help. I managed to get it working.

So I had to get the object mapping from PlugLead and not the class itself so it's actually

```
def encode(self,letter):
  for item in self.arr:
    if letter in item:
      a = PlugLead(item.mapping)
      return a.encode(letter)
```

And I use the encode function from PlugLead to actually encode it